# Fail when start a new container with elasticsearch 5.0

Tags: elasticsearch, docker

I run:

```
$ docker run --rm -ti -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 elasticsearch
```

But I can't start elasticsearch 5.0, here the log:

```
Unable to find image 'elasticsearch:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/elasticsearch

43c265008fae: Already exists 
af36d2c7a148: Already exists 
2b7b4d10e1c1: Already exists 
9f7579daddb2: Already exists 
a985511f2468: Already exists 
6c2b485fcc3e: Already exists 
00b73c83b440: Already exists 
a38975861823: Pull complete 
b9d0b4aaf934: Pull complete 
f5f25bb3de04: Pull complete 
93426e1e8953: Pull complete 
590c2ab9b639: Pull complete 
31bf48850601: Pull complete 
21aad7ce70fa: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:29205bca045c8d083f777dfc453f4f1ff3d2c08ea4f529f88795166c58e5607e
Status: Downloaded newer image for elasticsearch:latest
[2016-10-31T20:56:22,023][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
[2016-10-31T20:56:22,129][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [N-vpIo0] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/sda8)]], net usable_space [48.7gb], net total_space [98.3gb], spins? [possibly], types [ext4]
[2016-10-31T20:56:22,130][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [N-vpIo0] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2016-10-31T20:56:22,130][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [N-vpIo0] node name [N-vpIo0] derived from node ID; set [node.name] to override
[2016-10-31T20:56:22,132][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [N-vpIo0] version[5.0.0], pid[1], build[253032b/2016-10-26T05:11:34.737Z], OS[Linux/3.16.0-4-amd64/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_102/25.102-b14]
[2016-10-31T20:56:22,785][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [N-vpIo0] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2016-10-31T20:56:22,785][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [N-vpIo0] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2016-10-31T20:56:22,785][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [N-vpIo0] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2016-10-31T20:56:22,785][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [N-vpIo0] loaded module [lang-groovy]
[2016-10-31T20:56:22,785][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [N-vpIo0] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2016-10-31T20:56:22,785][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [N-vpIo0] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2016-10-31T20:56:22,785][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [N-vpIo0] loaded module [percolator]
[2016-10-31T20:56:22,785][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [N-vpIo0] loaded module [reindex]
[2016-10-31T20:56:22,785][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [N-vpIo0] loaded module [transport-netty3]
[2016-10-31T20:56:22,785][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [N-vpIo0] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2016-10-31T20:56:22,786][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [N-vpIo0] no plugins loaded
[2016-10-31T20:56:22,875][WARN ][o.e.d.s.g.GroovyScriptEngineService] [groovy] scripts are deprecated, use [painless] scripts instead
[2016-10-31T20:56:24,241][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [N-vpIo0] initialized
[2016-10-31T20:56:24,241][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [N-vpIo0] starting ...
[2016-10-31T20:56:24,380][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [N-vpIo0] publish_address {172.17.0.4:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300}
[2016-10-31T20:56:24,389][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapCheck     ] [N-vpIo0] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap checks
ERROR: bootstrap checks failed
max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] likely too low, increase to at least [262144]
[2016-10-31T20:56:24,400][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [N-vpIo0] stopping ...
[2016-10-31T20:56:24,426][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [N-vpIo0] stopped
[2016-10-31T20:56:24,426][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [N-vpIo0] closing ...
[2016-10-31T20:56:24,433][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [N-vpIo0] closed
```

Please, How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said at the [Docker image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/) in *Host Setup* section:

> Note: since 5.0, Elasticsearch only listens on localhost by default,
> so this image sets network.host to 0.0.0.0 (given that localhost is
> not terribly useful in the Docker context).
>
> As a result, Elasticsearch is more strict about the bootstrap checks
> that it performs, especially when checking the value of
> vm.max_map_count which is not namespaced and thus must be set to an
> acceptable value on the host (as opposed to simply using --sysctl on
> docker run).

So you just have to execute this on the host machine:

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

And you are good to go with the 5.0.0 version

To set this value permanently, update the `vm.max_map_count` setting in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. To verify after rebooting, run `sysctl vm.max_map_count`.

[More information here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/vm-max-map-count.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem related with virtual memory settings, the following command should works:

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

More details can be found here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/vm-max-map-count.html